# How to stop this span from disappearing when onmouseover displays a hidden div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**The Issue**

The span with ID `topnavbar` keeps disappearing when `onmouseover` changes the display on a hidden div from none to block. After onmouseout the span reappears, how do I ensure that the span remains there the whole time? Also, you may wonder on the positioning of elements in my code but it is due to the wacky CSS that things are the wya they are. I don't really mind any tweaks so long as the span with content `TESTING123` is placed before the image of the shopping cart anf of course the div with the text shopping cart (0) in it.

Here is JSFiddle that doesn't work??? The code works fine in a blank HTML file but just incase you want it in a JSFiddle here you go... https://jsfiddle.net/Please_Reply/osqnweda/5/

Otherwise, the original code is as below...

```
<head>
<style>
body{ /* Applies to the <body> tag */
    margin:0px; /* Sets the margin on all sides to 0px */
}
.container{ /* The container class */
    width:100%; /* This sets the width */
    height:100%; /* This sets the height */
    background-color:white; /* Sets the background colour */
    font-family:"Myriad Pro"; /* Sets the font family */
}
.header{ /* The header class */
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white; /* The sets the colour of the font */
}
div{
    display: inline-block; /* Sets the display type */
    float:left; /* Sets the float position */
}
#one, #two, #three, #four{
    background-color:black;
    height:90px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:25px;
}
#slider{
    background-color:blue;
    height:10px;
    width:100px;
    position: absolute; /* Sets the position to a specific type */
    left: 0; /* Sets the number of pixels from the left that this object is placed */
    bottom:0; /* Sets the number of pixels from the bottom that this object is placed */
}
.inside{
    margin-left:30px; /* Specifies the margin from the left side */
    margin-right:30px; /* Specifies the margin from the right side */
    padding-top:7px; /* Specifies the padding from the top side */
    pointer-events:none; /* Specifies the cursor events */
    margin-top:25px; /* Specifies the margin from the top side */
}
#shoppingTab{
    display:none;
    height:670px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-2px;
    border-radius:10px;
    color:black;
    border:1px solid #323232;
    padding:10px;
    float:right;
    z-index:50;
}
.smallProduct{
    height:50px;
    width:390px;
    float:left;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-size:16px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.smallProduct:hover{
    border:2px solid blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> <!-- This is the container -->
    <div class="header"> <!-- This is the header -->
        <div style="float:left"> <!-- This is the logo -->
            <img src="logo.png" height="120px"/>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; font-family:'Myriad Pro'; background-image:url(images/loginsignupbar.png); width:535.1px; height:30px">
            <div onmouseover="tabDisplay('block')" id="shopcartbar" style="float:right; font-size:24px; margin-top:-7px">
            <img src="images/shoppingCart.png" height="30px"/>&nbsp;Shopping Cart (<span id="numberOfItems">0</span>)&nbsp;
            </div>
            <div id="shoppingTab" onmouseout="tabDisplay('none')">
            Shopping Cart<br />
                <div class="smallProduct" style="margin-top:5px" id="thmbproduct0"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct1"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct2"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct3"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct4"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct5"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct6"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct7"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct8"></div>
                Total: $<span id="totalPrice">00</span>.00
            </div>
            <span id="topnavbar" style="float:right; font-size:24px; margin-top:5.5px">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; clear:right"> <!-- This is the navigation menu -->
            <div style="position:relative"> <!-- This is the container of the navigation menu -->
                <div id="slider"></div> <!-- This is the slider bar -->
                <a href="link.html"><div id="one" class="item"><div class="inside">Button 1</div></div></a> <!-- This is just one of the buttons -->
                <a href="link2.html"><div id="two" class="item"><div class="inside">Button 2</div></div></a>
                <a href="link3.html"><div id="three" class="item"><div class="inside">Button 3</div></div></a>
                <a href="link4.html"><div id="four" class="item"><div class="inside">Button 4</div></div></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
document.getElementById("topnavbar").innerHTML = "TESTING 123";

function tabDisplay(displayStatus){
    shoppingTab.style.display = displayStatus;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slider").animate({
    "left": $('#three').position().left + "px",
    "width": $('#three').width() + "px"
  }, 0);

  $(".item").hover(function() {
    $("#slider").stop();
    $("#slider").animate({
      "left": $(this).position().left + "px",
      "width": $(this).width() + "px"
    }, 500);
  });

  $(".item").on("mouseout", function() {
    $("#slider").stop();
    $("#slider").animate({
      "left": $('#three').position().left + "px",
      "width": $('#three').width() + "px"
    }, 500);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian I have gained over 100 reputation since you helped me out last :) but I still need your help

Answer (score 0):

Hi without looking too deep into your code. But how about you add a css snippet to the topnavbar.

```
.topnavbar {
  position:absolute;
}
```

That should keep your span visible.

Comment: sorry but that didn't work, just tried on the original HTML file, thanks for taking the time to respond though! :)

Comment: Sorry to hear that do you mind sending the link to ur website I can take a deeper look at it.

Comment: It isn't up on a server but the full code should be in the OP. Just copy it into a blank HTML file, add the !DOCTYPE and <head> tags etc. and then save as a .html file instead of .txt but I am sure you know how to do that anyway :)

Comment: My slab of code in the OP is only missing this at the top, which I omitted to save space. Here... <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: Try to add this to the topnavbar thingy position:absolute;
The reason why it disappears is because the shopping cart div actually pushes it away. by setting the position to absolute it will stay there. Then all you have to do is align it in the position. Hope that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer:**

By placing the `<span id='topnavbar'>` element *in front* of the hidden `<div id='shoppingTab'>` element and also applying a `float: right;` to it as well, the issue appears to have been resolved.

To understand the issue specifically, when you float elements, you have to consider what side you want them to break on; the right side (natural reading) or the left.  By having the `<span id='topnavbar'>` element after the hidden one, the float flow was being throw off in terms of what was seen and what was intended to be seen.

Also, when floating elements, the order they are placed in the HTML code plays a key role in how they render.  It is hard to explain but notice how `<div id='shopcartbar'>` appears first in the HTML code but renders last (or second) when viewed on the page.

```
<span id="topnavbar" style="float:right;"></span>
<div id="shoppingTab" onmouseout="tabDisplay('none')">Shopping Cart
  <br />
  <div class="smallProduct" style="margin-top:5px" id="thmbproduct0"></div>
  <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct1"></div>
  <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct2"></div>
  <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct3"></div>
  <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct4"></div>
  <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct5"></div>
  <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct6"></div>
  <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct7"></div>
  <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct8"></div>
  Total: $<span id="totalPrice">00</span>.00
</div>
```

**Old Answer:**

There is definitely something off with the inline CSS formatting.  I recommend doing a complete overhual of that page by putting the inlineCSS in a style sheet for readability and hierarchical flow (basically put all the inline styles in the stylesheet - give it a new class if you have you).

Update the span#topnavbar to the following:

```
<span id="topnavbar" style="float:none; font-size:24px; clear: none; right: -175px; position: relative;"></span>
```

Lastly, you may want to also consider camel-case for readability as well.

```css
#topnavbar {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      /* Applies to the <body> tag */
      margin: 0px;
      /* Sets the margin on all sides to 0px */
    }
    
    .container {
      /* The container class */
      width: 100%;
      /* This sets the width */
      height: 100%;
      /* This sets the height */
      background-color: white;
      /* Sets the background colour */
      font-family: "Myriad Pro";
      /* Sets the font family */
    }
    
    .header {
      /* The header class */
      width: 100%;
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
      /* The sets the colour of the font */
    }
    
    div {
      display: inline-block;
      /* Sets the display type */
      float: left;
      /* Sets the float position */
    }
    
    #one,
    #two,
    #three,
    #four {
      background-color: black;
      height: 90px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    
    #slider {
      background-color: blue;
      height: 10px;
      width: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      /* Sets the position to a specific type */
      left: 0;
      /* Sets the number of pixels from the left that this object is placed */
      bottom: 0;
      /* Sets the number of pixels from the bottom that this object is placed */
    }
    
    .inside {
      margin-left: 30px;
      /* Specifies the margin from the left side */
      margin-right: 30px;
      /* Specifies the margin from the right side */
      padding-top: 7px;
      /* Specifies the padding from the top side */
      pointer-events: none;
      /* Specifies the cursor events */
      margin-top: 25px;
      /* Specifies the margin from the top side */
    }
    
    #shoppingTab {
      display: none;
      height: 670px;
      width: 400px;
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      position: relative;
      margin-top: -2px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: black;
      border: 1px solid #323232;
      padding: 10px;
      float: right;
      z-index: 50;
    }
    
    .smallProduct {
      height: 50px;
      width: 390px;
      float: left;
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-radius: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .smallProduct:hover {
      border: 2px solid blue;
    }
    
    span#topnavbar {
      float: right;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- This is the container -->
    <div class="header">
      <!-- This is the header -->
      <div style="float:left">
        <!-- This is the logo -->
        <img src="logo.png" height="120px" />
      </div>
      <div style="float:right; font-family:'Myriad Pro'; background-image:url(images/loginsignupbar.png); width:535.1px; height:30px">
        <div onmouseover="tabDisplay('block')" id="shopcartbar" style="float:right; font-size:24px; margin-top:-7px">
          <img src="images/shoppingCart.png" height="30px" />&nbsp;Shopping Cart (<span id="numberOfItems">0</span>)&nbsp;
        </div>
        <span id="topnavbar"></span>
        <div id="shoppingTab" onmouseout="tabDisplay('none')">
          Shopping Cart
          <br />
          <div class="smallProduct" style="margin-top:5px" id="thmbproduct0"></div>
          <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct1"></div>
          <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct2"></div>
          <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct3"></div>
          <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct4"></div>
          <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct5"></div>
          <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct6"></div>
          <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct7"></div>
          <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct8"></div>
          Total: $<span id="totalPrice">00</span>.00
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="float:right; clear:right">
        <!-- This is the navigation menu -->
        <div style="position:relative">
          <!-- This is the container of the navigation menu -->
          <div id="slider"></div>
          <!-- This is the slider bar -->
          <a href="link.html">
            <div id="one" class="item">
              <div class="inside">Button 1</div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <!-- This is just one of the buttons -->
          <a href="link2.html">
            <div id="two" class="item">
              <div class="inside">Button 2</div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="link3.html">
            <div id="three" class="item">
              <div class="inside">Button 3</div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="link4.html">
            <div id="four" class="item">
              <div class="inside">Button 4</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  document.getElementById("topnavbar").innerHTML = "TESTING 123";

  function tabDisplay(displayStatus) {
    shoppingTab.style.display = displayStatus;
  }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider").animate({
      "left": $('#three').position().left + "px",
      "width": $('#three').width() + "px"
    }, 0);

    $(".item").hover(function() {
      $("#slider").stop();
      $("#slider").animate({
        "left": $(this).position().left + "px",
        "width": $(this).width() + "px"
      }, 500);
    });

    $(".item").on("mouseout", function() {
      $("#slider").stop();
      $("#slider").animate({
        "left": $('#three').position().left + "px",
        "width": $('#three').width() + "px"
      }, 500);
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry but I cannot have fixed dimensions such as right: -175px, it must sit directly next to the other span. This site's widths are different depending on the screen resolution so I can't use fixed dimensions like left, right, top or bottom. It just needs to sit in front of the other span.

Comment: And so once I removed the right property, and put float back to right to get it sitting where it should be, it didn't work. I kept the rest but it didn't work

Comment: You can do some basic math calculations (using JavaScript) to determine how far right it needs to be pushed and then apply that number dynamically to the CSS (using jQuery).  I will update my answer showing this perhaps later today.

Comment: Your new answer looks promising... I will test it when I have the opportunity later today :)

Comment: Sorry but once I used this code in my website, it stopped other functionality, and I mean it impaired my site severely. The hover over function didn't work not to mention other things stopped working entirely.

Comment: Per my original answer, you may want to consider overhauling what could be toxic HTML.  My case in point is that if you run the code snippet I provided you will see the solution offered as my new answer working as intended.  I did not edit any of the original code you provided save for re-positioning the `topnav` element.  If after, having applied that one simple change, your entire layout breaks, then you may a bigger problem.

Comment: I will investigate this further when I get the chance thank you